# I would like to have inner round corners using circles but the corners should be transparent

Tags: html, css

I have this code but it will only work on a white background is there a way to change this code so it will work on any colored background.

There are many other solution online however they each have problems like for example the are hard to scale on large and small screen.

Thank you for your help.

```css
body {
  background:#fff;
}
.corner {
background:#fff;
height:20px;
width:20px;    
position:absolute;
}
.sw {
left: -2px;
bottom: -2px;
border-radius: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
border-top: 2px solid #000;
border-right: 2px solid #000;
}
.se {
right: -2px;
bottom: -2px;
border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
border-top: 2px solid #000;
border-left: 2px solid #000;
}
.nw {
left: -2px;
top: -2px;
border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
border-right: 2px solid #000;
}
.ne {
right: -2px;
top: -2px;
border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
border-left: 2px solid #000;
}

.box {
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
    border: solid 2px black;
    background:#FFD700;
    border-radius: 5px -5px 5px 5px;
}

.content{
  margin:80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="ne corner"></div>
    <div class="nw corner"></div>
    <div class="se corner"></div>
    <div class="sw corner"></div>
  <div class="content">
  <h1>Golden Ticket</h1> 
    <p>Some legal text here...</p>
  <div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://css-generators.com/custom-corners/#2

Answer (score -1):

If your goal is flexibility, then you could make a css color variable:

```
:root{
--color: red;
}
```

and then apply it on your circles and your page:

```
.box{
 background: var(--color);
}

body{
background: var(--color);
}
```

if you then change the css variable, the changes are reflected both in your circles and in your page background.

If your goal is to have a more dynamic (adaptive) way of this figure. That is more complex, and will probably involve having to use css masks in combination with drop-shadow or stacked css masks. I hope this puts you on the right path.